# Ionic BLE Connection Issues

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using the Ionic Native BLE plugin to scan and connect to bluetooth devices. I'm able to get the plugin to list available devices, but I'm unable to get it to show already paired devices. This is the plugin I'm using:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble/

After searching through the documentation and finding examples, I've come to the conclusion that using this plugin to list already paired devices is just not possible. Is this the correct conclusion?

If so, do you know of any other plugins I could use to facilitate the looking up of paired bluetooth devices? I'm using Ionic 3.

Answer (score 0):

We have been working on a simple BLE button and had the same issues. The only way we found out how to do this was to disconnect the button on app close (which the latest BLE version seems to do). We save the device ID (localStorage) when a user connects a device and then when the app starts up again the user has to wake up the device and the app starts scanning on startup. If the saved device id is the the id as your locally saved id it connects automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you, or anyone, wants to try other plugin, you can also try this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/bluetoothle/

I first started using the same plugin that you use. After I encountered some difficult issues due to the strange operations of some bluetooth devices, I tried the second plugin and I found it to be better. That was three years ago and I can't say how the other plugin has improved in the present. One thing I like with the bluetoothle plugin is that it has many methods available and that gives more control to the bluetooth operations. You can look at these methods in its repo:

https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle